# Ошибка Cannot find module при запуске gulp

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, gulp

Ребят подскажите пожалуйста из за чего может возникнуть вот эта ошибка при запуске gulp[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно не найден модуль, но это не точно.

Comment: А как это можно исправить?

Comment: Я конечно же пытался пошутить, но понял что не вышло. 
Я не силен как это работает в win. но похоже что так же как и везде. Если у вас не хватает модуля, его нужно установить. npm install, yarn install ??

Comment: Просто не совсем понимаю какой именно модуль устанавливать.

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать переустановить модуль.

```
npm uninstall gulp -g
npm install gulp -g
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]